# Linear programming, a non standard handling of absolute value

Tags: linear-programming, convex-optimization

This is really a basic (undergrad) question in LP but still i would like to
clarify it for myself to be sure. I have a minimization problem from the sort $\min \sum_i |x_i|$ s.t $Ax \le b$.
I've seen that the standard way to convert it to LP is to represent $x_i$ as the difference
of two non negative variables. We question is, can i also handle it like so : 
add a new variable t : $|x_i|=t_i$ and get
$$\min \sum_i t_i \\ 
Ax \le b \\ 
-t_i \le x_i \le t_i $$
Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formulation ensures that $|x_i|=t_i$ in every *optimal* solution. However, this does not hold for an arbitrary *feasible* point.

Picky people could then complain that your formulation isn't entirely correct. However, as long as you don't change your objective function nor use $t_i$ in any other constraint, then you will be fine in practice.

[This blog post describes several ways to model absolute values](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.fr/2012/07/modeling-absolute-values.html).